# Printing to the same line in python

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the code I'm currently using. I saw this on another question, but the output I got was

10/10
9/10
8/10
7/10
6/10
5/10

---

```
def damage(hp, newhp, maxhp):
    for x in range(hp-newhp):
        print(str(hp-x)+'/'+str(maxhp), end='\r')
    print('\r'+str(newhp)+'/'+str(maxhp), end='/r')
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: how to fix my code

Comment: I'm trying to make the output change and the health go down by one each time it changes it

Answer (score 0):

end should be `end=''`

```
 def damage(hp, newhp, maxhp):
        for x in range(hp-newhp):
            print(str(hp-x)+'/'+str(maxhp), end='')
        print('\r'+str(newhp)+'/'+str(maxhp), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
for x in range(hp-newhp):
    print("{}/{}".format(hp-x, maxhp))
```